# How to call a setInterval function

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Instead of `setInterval` running upon refresh, I'd like it to run upon clicking on the start button & go up to time. I tried almost every variation for the past hours & it didn't work without any errors.

Instead the timer stops which makes sense if time > 2. Therefore, I am not sure how I can make timer restart once `start` gets click and for the timer to stop once time reached (i.e. 2 seconds)

HTML

```
<script src='https://api.chipware.co.za/js/flipclock-min.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>
<button style="width:200px; height: 50px;" id="start">Start</button>
<button style="width:200px; height: 50px;"onclick="submit()" id="stop">Submit</button>
```

JS

```
let time = 2;
var clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(0, {
clockFace: 'HourlyCounter',
countdown: false });

function submit(){
clock.stop();
}

var element_ = document.getElementById("start");
    element_.addEventListener('click', function(){
    start(time);
    });

function start(time){
countup = setInterval(function () { 
    if(clock.getTime().time > time) { 
    clock.stop();
    clearInterval(countup);
    }
    else{
    var element = document.getElementById("stop");
    element.addEventListener('click', function(){
    submit();
    });
}
})};
```

Also unsure why this code runs w/o error by itself but in chrome extension, it gives:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).FlipClock is not a function
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you want to do? What is the "didn't work"? Any errors?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get any error or else I would've written. I just expect `setInterval()` to restart upon clocking on `start` button, but it doesn't. Hence, I am confused. The timer actually stops instead which makes sense because time is > 2.  Thus, I am confused how to make timer restart upon start button and stop once reached `time`.

Comment: `time` and `clock` are `undefined`. Why put an `EventListener` inside an `interval`?

Comment: my sincerest apologies, I forgot that clock wasn't part of the code I pasted. I'm quite confused about your question, as I thought I did the reverse.

Comment: oh you meant, in the `start()`. Tbh I didn't how else I could've stopped the interval with a button click

Comment: If you want to "reset" an interval, you can assign your `setInterval()` call into a variable, for example `let myInterval = setInterval(myFunction,15);` then you can simply call `cearInterval(myInterval);` and then re-assign a new `setInterval(myFunction,15);` into `myInterval`. I hope this helps!

Comment: So you mean I should take out function `start()` and replace `start(time);` with `clearinterval(countup)`? cause that didn't work :(

Comment: In fact, ` clearInterval(countup);` in the `start()` doesn't even clear the time in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Your missing flipclock library I just added and update the code now it work.

```js
let time = 2;
var clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(0, {
clockFace: 'HourlyCounter',
countdown: false });

function submit(){
clock.stop();
}

var element_ = document.getElementById("start");
    element_.addEventListener('click', function(){
    start(time);
    });

function start(time){

countup = setInterval(function () { 
console.log(clock.getTime().time ,time)
    if(clock.getTime().time > time) { 
    clock.stop();
    clearInterval(countup);
    }
    else{
    var element = document.getElementById("stop");
    element.addEventListener('click', function(){
    submit();
    });
}
})};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.7/flipclock.min.js" integrity="sha512-Vy4ftjkcjamOFPNSK7Osn8kYhF7XDcLWPiRvSmdimNscisyC8MkhDlAHSt+psegxRzd/q6wUC/VFhQZ6P2hBOw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<button style="width:200px; height: 50px;" id="start">Start</button>
<button style="width:200px; height: 50px;"onclick="submit()" id="stop">Submit</button>
```

Comment: would you mind explaining what the `integrity` is about or provide a reference? I do call flipclock js before running the code. Sorry if it wasn't in the original code as it didn't make any difference to the error. As well as, I am not sure how your code helps with the reset problem.